# I dont have index.html, I have index.php. Where does my code go?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I know i might get downvoted for asking this but i really need to know:

I have index.php and no index.html

In my index.php, i dont see a body section.

I need to add some code to the body section.

I'm using wordpress theme named: "responsive".

Here is the link for it:

https://en-ca.wordpress.org/themes/responsive/

I would really appreciate it if someone could have a look and let me know where i can find the  section.

Thanks

Comment: I did do research and couldnt find the solution. I didnt know it was the end of the world to ask a question...

Comment: Read the guidelines on asking a good question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Yousuf everything you need to know is here on how WordPress templates work https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 2):

First, learn how to use WordPress. WordPress themes are located at `wp-content/themes/{your-theme-name}/`.

The `index.php` in web root does not relate to your user interface.

Comment: Are you saying i should find the index.html there? I checked and its not there either.

Comment: @Yousuf your not looking for an index.php file, that's something you dont go near, you edit the relevant theme files

Comment: Raptor gave the path above, but i dont use wordpress, so i dont know the specifics

Comment: WordPress uses PHP, instead of HTML. Basically, WordPress' theme consists of `index.php`, `header.php` and `footer.php` (and many other theme files). The layout structure is in these files.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is based on php so that means that you won't be writing purely html files. Instead of index.html your main page will be index.php.
In index.php you can still write 100% pure html, but you can also mix it with php. In index.html you can't add php code.

Comment: So does that mean that i can add the "body" section myself?

Comment: PHP is also based on HTML. @Yousuf actually what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to add this code to the <body> section: <div class="count-particles"> <span class="js-count-particles">--</span> particles </div>

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUzihD4JBQU ; thats an example of what i need to do

Comment: Yes you can add the "body" yourself. Just write everything as if it's an index.html file if you're going for that :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll find HTML in the theme's .php files. The `<body>` tag starts in header.php and you'll find `</body>` in footer.php.

There will also be an index.php, and/or front-page.php, and/or home.php file, but those aren't necessarily going to match up to your experience with index.html files -- they're used to output the content of your website's homepage, the blog page, or archives pages like category pages. Take a look at https://wphierarchy.com/ to learn more about what each theme file does.

Make a backup copy of your theme. Then you can start editing these files to see what they correspond with.

Comment: YOUR THE BEST! I found it! I looked everywhere except the header.php...i figured the body wouldnt be in the header. Bad assumption on my part.